# How to check using DAX if multiple columns for group of records contain specific text?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with columns Date, MainID, Par1, Par2 and Par3 like below

[image]

If for the date and MainID values any of Par1, Par2 and Par3 values contain "UNMATCH" then it should indicate "UNMATCH" overall. I am looking for output like in "Overall" column.

I have tried Group By, Contains and other options but couldn't crack this issue.

Any idea where can I start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my funky suggestion:

```
Overall =
VAR _table = 
    CALCULATETABLE (
        UNION ( 
            VALUES ( 'Table'[Par1] ) , 
            VALUES ( 'Table'[Par2] ) ,
            VALUES ( 'Table'[Par3] )
        ), 
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Date] , 'Table'[Main ID] )
    )
RETURN
IF ( 
    CONTAINS (
        _table ,
        'Table'[Par1] ,
        "UNMATCH"
    ),
    "UNMATCH" ,
    "MATCH"
)
```

Edit: And a slightly more boring (but perhaps more intuitive) suggestion:

```
Another Overall = 
VAR _table = 
    CALCULATETABLE (
        'Table' ,
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Date] , 'Table'[Main ID] )
    )
RETURN 
SWITCH (
    TRUE , 
    CONTAINS( _table , 'Table'[Par1] , "UNMATCH" ) , "UNMATCH" ,
    CONTAINS( _table , 'Table'[Par2] , "UNMATCH" ) , "UNMATCH" ,
    CONTAINS( _table , 'Table'[Par3] , "UNMATCH" ) , "UNMATCH" ,
    "MATCH"
)
```

Comment: I am using your 2nd solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that it works as required. I would consider implementing the suggestion from @mkRabbani instead, due to it being a more efficient solution in terms of data modelling and data model compression. As a rule: Implement things as close to the database as possible.

In this case, calculating the column in Power Query may be better than doing the calculation in DAX after the data is loaded to VertiPaq. The only real showstopper is if the transform in Power Query is extremely slow.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable to do this in M query, you can follow these below instructions-

Go to **Power query editor** and then open the **Advanced Editor** for your table. Now add this below code to your existing code and you will have a **new column** in your table with your expected output-

```
let
    //#"your_last_step_name",
    
    //---- Add this below code with adjusting the last step name

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"your_last_step_name", "Custom", each if [Par1] = "UNMATCH" then [Par1] else if [Par2] = "UNMATCH" then [Par2] else [Par3]),
    _grouped = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Date", "MainID"}, {{"max", each List.Max([Custom]), type text}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Date", "MainID"}, _grouped, {"Date", "MainID"}, "_grouped", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded _grouped" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "_grouped", {"max"}, {"Overall"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded _grouped",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

here is the final output-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use "Groupby" or more complicated function, "If else statement" with "Distinct count" will do, the only difference is that you need to store each count in a variable, then compared the value:

```
Overall = 
var par1 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Par1]),
            FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[MainID]=EARLIER(Sheet1[MainID])),
                FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Date]=EARLIER(Sheet1[Date])),Sheet1[Par1]="UNMATCH")

var par2 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Par2]),
            FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[MainID]=EARLIER(Sheet1[MainID])),
                FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Date]=EARLIER(Sheet1[Date])),Sheet1[Par2]="UNMATCH")

var par3 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Par3]),
            FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[MainID]=EARLIER(Sheet1[MainID])),
                FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Date]=EARLIER(Sheet1[Date])),Sheet1[Par3]="UNMATCH")
return
IF(par1 + par2 + par3 >=1, "UNMATCH", "MATCH")
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the correct solution. What I am looking for is that if the MainID and Date are same values and if any of Par1, Par2 and Par3 values contain "UNMATCH" then overall status for that group should be "UNMATCH". Check the first 2 records in my example. Also for the 3rd record when all 3 pars were "MATCH" the Overall status was "MATCH". So, the main challenge is number of records for a combination of Date and MainID. This is the reason I tried groupby.

Comment: Check my edited answer, it return your expected output, accept the answer if help :)